# CPU fan not running on Arch linux

Tags: linux, laptop, fan, overheating

I'm running Arch Linux on **Acer Aspire E5-575G [V1.25]**

and some of the other installed packages related:

```
xf86videointel, intelucode, xf86videointel, libvainteldriver, nvidialts, nvidiautils, nvidiasettings
```

It's been a few weeks since I realized that fan is not spinning at all causing overheating.
I don't know for how long it's been like this and what I did that caused this. But I remember that not long ago it was working just fine.
I searched a lot and found a lot of suggested commands but unfortunately none of them solved the problem.

```
$ uname -r
5.10.50-1-lts
```

What I tried so far is:

```
$ ls /proc/acpi/fan
ls: cannot access '/proc/acpi/fan': No such file or directory
```

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          16.78 V  
curr1:         0.00 A  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.5°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +58.0°C
```

```
$ sudo pwmconfig
[...]
/usr/bin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

```
$ lsmod | grep fan
[displays nothing, exiting with status code 1]
```

PS. and also this command:

```
$ ls -1 /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/acpi
acpi_configfs.ko.xz
acpi_extlog.ko.xz
acpi_ipmi.ko.xz
acpi_pad.ko.xz
acpi_tad.ko.xz
apei
custom_method.ko.xz
dptf
ec_sys.ko.xz
nfit
sbshc.ko.xz
sbs.ko.xz
video.ko.xz
```

Answer (score 1):

The fan not running is more often a hardware issue than a software one. I know a few low power portable machines where the fan is typically not meant to run, but on those the fan is still controlled by the system firmware and not the operating system.

Unless you have specifically run commands that disable the fan, or can prove that it runs in a "clean" Live USB distro, then I would be surprised if this is a software problem.

The first thing to try would be to remove the battery, hold the power button for a few seconds to discharge any capacitors on the motherboard, and then replace the battery and power up again. This should reset the motherboard firmware controller and resume normal operation.

If the fan still doesn't move then it is probably broken and I would replace the fan.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a hardware problem because the outputs of the above commands show that fan is not recognized

Comment: The fan not being "recognised" simply means that the operating system has no idea that there is a fan. It's not up to the operating system to run the fan in the first place, it's up to the hardware to run the fan and, if the manufacturer thinks it worth it, to expose a software interface to allow control. If there is no interface then I would assume that it is 100% hardware controlled, not the other way around.  I have a laptop with a fan that is entirely undetectable to the operating system yet I know it works because I can hear it when the system is under load.

Comment: If your fan were software controllable then you would see an interface via the commands you ran regardless of whether the actual fan itself had a fault. You are addressing a system firmware interface that exposes fan controls, not the fan itself, and if those interfaces are missing then that is a system firmware issue. Hence my first stop being to reset the motherboard by removing the battery. If there is still no interface then either your fan is dead or the fan controller is faulty. The fan controller is less likely than the fan itself and the fan should be relatively easy to replace.

Comment: Now I see. Referring to the `reset the motherboard` I have to say the battery is built-in. How do you suggest that I should the resetting?

Comment: Apparently you should have a recessed "battery reset" button on the underside of your laptop. https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/393009/Acer+Aspire+E5-575G-53VG+turned+off+and+doesn't+boot

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was such a thing. I did that and then rebooted after a few minutes. Now I have to wait and see if it works.